# Ruby запись объекта в YAML файл

Tags: ruby

При каждом вызове метода `save` имеющаяся информация в файле перезатирается. Подскажите верно ли написан метод? Возможно, что то упустил.

```
def save(nickname)
      @code_breakers << Player.new(nickname, @current_try)
      File.open('result.yaml', 'w') { |file| file.puts(code_breakers.to_yaml) }
end
```

Comment: А что говорят тесты? :)

Comment: с тестами пока относительно сложно( Rsprec только начал изучать. В связи с чем не могу сообразить как правильно написать тест на проверку перезаписывается ли файл.

Comment: Да хоть на minitest напишите, это не принципиально. Как проверить? Очень просто, в тесте есть старое значение и новое, проверяете есть ли в нём старое, проверяете есть ли новое.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы открываете файл в неверном формате. Нужен не "w" (запись), а "a" - добавление.
Ответ - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7085595/file-opening-mode-in-ruby